# SATA/SAS HDD Connector

Tags: hard-drive, sata, connector, sas

Coming here out of relative inexperience. I have recently bought a hard drive on eBay advertised as a 2TB SATA II 7.2K RPM HDD. Most of this seems to check out upon receiving it, except for one thing. When I went to connect it, I realized that neither cable was able to connect to it because the notch in between pin groups was bridged and had pins on the other side. I did some searching and found that this seems to be the interface that I had tried to avoid, SAS. It said it was refurbished and the tray says 2TB SATA on it, but the connector is quite clearly an SAS connector. I can't find any further good info on the tray, board, or connector itself, and it seems that the wrong connector was put on. However, I'm not sure. Could anyone with more experience tell me if I'm right or wrong, and how to fix this? I could return it, but I want to do this pretty quickly to get my new PC working, I think it may be fixable, and I am interested to learn more about this. Also, it was a steal at $30 for the thing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Maybe give us a picture of what you have?  You mentioned a **tray**?  Do you have a SATA drive in a SAS tray that is incompatible or something?  I am guessing this is for a server or something?  You can have the right drive, and wrong tray.

Comment: At the very least we need a part and model number

Comment: I voted to leave this question open when there were already 4 close votes. If this question is closed and then voted to reopen, please pm me in chat and I will VTR.

Answer (score 0):

SAS controllers can read SATA drives, however SATA controllers cannot read SAS drives.  If you have a standard SATA controller and a SAS drive, they are not compatible.

Unless you want to invest in a SAS controller, you should return the drive.